# Feed Import Error

Tags: 7, feeds

This import was working, now I'm stumped on why it's breaking.

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 200 Debugging
>   information follows. Path: /batch?id=79&op=do StatusText: OK
>   ResponseText: Please register to continue....[lots more]

just a standard import: mylocal.com:8080/import
select import file: ~downloads/myexport.xml 
click [Import]

Everything is being done on local osx laptop.

- Drupal 7.22
- Feeds 7.x-2.0-alpha8

Since it seems to be an authentication issue for the batch, I assigned all permissions to all roles, including anonymous, for feeds and the relevant content create (on this local instances).

This can't be a big problem, I just don't see it...

Answer (score 0):

When upgrading Feeds, I have found that settings often get lost. It is not an extremely stable module.

Go to `/admin/structure/feeds` and edit your feed importer. Re-check all of your importer settings, and make sure they are correct. In particular, under processor settings make sure the *Author* is set to a user with sufficient permissions (usually *admin*).

Answer (score 0):

Feeds is fine.  The error reported above was caused by an unrelated custom module.  When that module was disabled, then the feed import succeeded.   Long live feeds.